# Typescript method return array multiple type

Tags: typescript

I want to return an array with a number and string type, and I don't want use any type in the parameter. How would I go about doing this?

```
export class Student {
  // don't use any how to realize it 
  method1: any[]() {
   return ['1', 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), like

```
method1() : (number | string)[] {
   return ['1', 1];
}
```